# Why am I receiving a ModuleNotFoundError (Flask and Heroku)

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am attempting to run a Flask app on a Heroku website. I keep receiving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. Which results in error H10s, which means that the app has crashed.

Most of the other posts that I have seen for ModuleNotFoundErrors do not have to do with Heroku.

The error that I recieved is shown below:

```
2019-03-26T21:48:51.850467+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-03-26T21:48:51.850469+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2019-03-26T21:48:51.850619+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-26 21:48:51 +0000] 
[10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-03-26T21:48:51.880416+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-26 21:48:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-03-26T21:48:51.880549+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-26 21:48:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-03-26T21:48:51.958542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-03-26T21:48:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-26T21:49:27.367113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pure-gorge-37718.herokuapp.com request_id=6ca268c7-0b35-4a07-b628-5a7299d12f81 fwd="143.229.174.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-26T21:49:27.892816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pure-gorge-37718.herokuapp.com request_id=0c7a5ac6-456c-489a-9eab-cdd94c8c68f2 fwd="143.229.174.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Why would this error only occur when I try to run this app on Heroku?

Comment: How do you run your app locally? What is does your `Procfile` contains? This can be related to your app and how the imports are structured, there can be thousands reasons to this error.

Comment: @CloC I use `git push heroku master` then `heroku run` to run locally. My `Procfile` contains `web: gunicorn app:FaceDetector/app.py\n`.

Comment: What if you run directly `gunicorn app:FaceDetector/app.py`? Do you experience the same kind error? It may be caused by the way you structured your project. Have you had a look at [gunicorn documentation](https://gunicorn.org/) on how to use it?

Comment: @CloC When I run `gunicorn app:FaceDetector/app.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'`. I have not taken a look at this documentation; I've just been relying on online guides and trial and error for making the Procfile, as I cannot find anywhere that explicitly states what I should put.

Comment: Copy/pasting code without understanding it lead to errors like the one you are experiencing. Apparently you are using windows, `gunicorn` being incompatible with it, you are going to have problems. Using it with heroku makes it possible, but adds more complexity. I would recommend starting with an easier flask project that runs localy, not using `gunicorn` or heroku. Once you are comfortable, see devops tools such as gunicorn or heroku.

Comment: @CloC My Flask program does run locally on localhost when I do `app.py` in the command line. I am now attempting to put it on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the `Procfile` to `web: gunicorn app:app` and moving all of the contents from FaceDetector to the root folder.